# How do I reset the minimap in version 3.5.3?

Tags: terraria

I'm wondering how to reset the mini-map for a Terraria world in version 3.5.3. My map isn't corrupted or anything but I've done a bunch of terraforming which looks super weird on the mini-map. I saw that there should be a `.map` file in the corresponding player's folder, but there was only one file in my players folder that I couldn't make sense of.

Comment: Ahh not sure what happened but after moving my player and world offline, checking the player .plr file then moving them back to the cloud the minimap for every world was deleted even ones I didn't touch. There is some minimap left on a previous world that appears to be what I explored since I moved that world off the clould a while ago. So that is super wierd not sure what happened. do I delete my question now or what.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two files that make up a player's "save" in Terraria: The .WLD world file (which contains structure information, including block types, chest contents, sign text, which bosses have been defeated, etc), and the .PLR player file (which contains inventory information, max/current health and mana, equipment, etc). Minimap data is saved in the player file, which means that a new character going into an old world would still have to walk around to fill in the minimap.

Since minimap data is tied to the character, it is impossible to delete/alter the minimap data without third party editing tools.

However, if you want to clear out the minimap, there is a workaround. On your current character, take off all equipment and deposit it into some chests. Then create a new character and re-equip all the gear from your old character. You'll still have to search for heart crystals to bring your new character's health back up, but this way your minimap is brand new and you still get to keep all your old equipment.